# 3D animation of time series in Plotly

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly

I'm prototyping some code to then bring in some more complex time series data (and a lot of it) but can't for the life of me figure out how to get the vector components to animate in the below code. The blue path looks good to start with then disappears on play. And secondly, only the x component displays on play. I've been working mostly off the tutorials on the [main plotly site so far](https://plot.ly/python/animations/), but, as the project builds complexity, my lack of expertise in plotly has let me down. I'm developing in an online Jupyter notebook if someone has any suggestions on how to make my code better. Thanks.

[image]
[image]

```
N = 50
vec_x, vec_y, vec_z = [0,0,0]
list_of_lists = []
choice = [-0.2, 0.2]
for i in range(N):
    vec_x = vec_x + np.random.choice(choice)
    vec_y = vec_y + np.random.choice(choice)
    vec_z = vec_z + np.random.choice(choice)
    list_of_lists.append([vec_x, vec_y, vec_z])
points = np.array(list_of_lists)
source = points.T

def frameMaker(i):
    """
    returns x,y,z dict of currently indexed frame by vector component key
    """
    scale = 10
    list_of_lists = dict({
    "x": [[source[0][i],scale * source[0][i+1]], [source[1][i],source[1][i]], [source[2][i],source[2][i]]],
    "y": [[source[0][i],source[0][i]], [source[1][i],scale * source[1][i+1]], [source[2][i], source[2][i]]],
    "z": [[source[0][i],source[0][i]], [source[1][i],source[1][i]], [source[2][i], scale * source[2][i+1]]]
    })
    return list_of_lists

#graphics
plt = go.Figure(
    data=[go.Scatter3d(
            x=source[0],
            y=source[1],
            z=source[2],
            mode="lines",
            line=dict(
                color="darkblue",
                width=2)),
        go.Scatter3d(
            x=source[0],
            y=source[1],
            z=source[2],
            mode="lines",
            line=dict(
                color="darkblue",
                width=2))
         ],
    layout = 
        go.Layout(
            title = go.layout.Title(text="Title | Total Frames: "+ str(N)),
            scene_aspectmode="cube",
            scene = dict(
                xaxis = dict(range=[-2,2], nticks=10, autorange=False),
                yaxis = dict(range=[-2,2], nticks=10, autorange=False),
                zaxis = dict(range=[-2,2], nticks=10, autorange=False)),
            updatemenus=[dict(type="buttons",
                          buttons=[dict(label="Play",
                                        method="animate",
                                        args=[None])])]
            ),
    frames=[go.Frame(
        data=[go.Scatter3d(
            x = [source[0][k]],
            y = [source[1][k]],
            z = [source[2][k]],
            mode="markers",
            marker=dict(color="red",size=10,opacity=0.5)),
        go.Scatter3d(
            x=frameMaker(k)["x"][0],
            y=frameMaker(k)["x"][1],
            z=frameMaker(k)["x"][2],
            line=dict(color='darkblue',width=2)),
        go.Scatter3d(
            x=frameMaker(k)["y"][0],
            y=frameMaker(k)["y"][1],
            z=frameMaker(k)["y"][2],
            line=dict(color='#bcbd22',width=2)),
        go.Scatter3d(
            x=frameMaker(k)["z"][0],
            y=frameMaker(k)["z"][1],
            z=frameMaker(k)["z"][2],
            line=dict(color='#d62728',width=2))],
        layout=go.Layout(
            title = go.layout.Title(text=str([k+1,list(map(lambda x: round(x,3), source.T[k]))]))
        )
        ) for k in range(N-1)
        ]
)
plt.show()
```